# Action Bar in API < 3.0 With Google Maps Compatability Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-fragmentactivity, android-compatibility

Yet another compatibility problem from me.

**BACKGROUND**

I have an application that works in all API's now that I downloaded a custom google maps compatibility support library which is an extension of the `Compatibility Support Library` and allows me the have fragments along with maps in API levels < 3.0. It does this by making me extend my activity by `FragmentActivity`, which due to this custom library is also a subclass of `MapActivity`.

**THE PROBLEM**

I also need to implement a tabbed `Action Bar` throughout my application on different API levels. It's possible to do this using `ActionBarSherlock`. However, that also involves downloading and extending my ``` Activity`` by ```FragmentActivity` using this custom library and thats a problem as I then lose the ability to have maps because I can't extend using both libraries versions?

**THE QUESTION**

How can I have both features in my application?

If this isn't the way to do it, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

So I have implemented a system where I can display the action bar in api's greater than 3.0 and not display if they aren't.

Here is the code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.show();
} else {
        //Do something else
}
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Would the best way to go about it be to create a custom *ActionBar Module* that is just a group of views with some functions to make it act and look like an action bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution that I came up with.

`ActionBarSherlock` wasn't an option for me due to the fact I was already using a version of the compatability library that allowed me to use `GoogleMaps` along with `Fragments` and if I used the `ActionBarSherlock` library I would have lost this functionality.

**My Solution**

I decided to implement my own custom `ActionBar` which is a combination of `Views` and `TextViews`.

I have one class extending `Fragment` (the android support version) called `CCActionBar` and this inflates three custom objects called `CCTab` which extend `TextView`. These three tabs (as it says in the name) are acting as my tabs so we override when they get touched, pass them to our `CCActionBar` which may then pass it onto our `MainActivity` to handle any navigation.

To detect if we need to create this `Custom Action Bar` due to API level I use the following code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   //setup a normal action bar because the api level supports it
} else {
   //setup our custom action bar
}
```

So that's my solution, it may not be the correct one but it works for me.

Any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to extend your `FragmentActivity` by `SherlockActivity` ?

Comment: I can't do that as it's already being extended by `FragmentActivity` which comes from the custom Google Maps library allowing me to use maps

Comment: Right I just check the SherlockActivity, I missed the name but you also got a "SherlockFragmentActivity" which extends "FragmentActivity"
It's seem you have to mimic this one and merge it with the other one